# Prove $\frac{n-1}{n^2+2} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I'm doing a university real analysis course and I'm practising proving the limits of sequences. I've been tasked prove $x_n = \frac{n-1}{n^2+2}$ converges.

Using algebra of limits we deduce.

$$x_n =\frac{n-1}{n^2+2} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{2}{n}} \implies x_n=0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$$

A limit exists if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$

$$n \geq N \implies |\frac{n-1}{n^2-2}-0| < \epsilon.$$

For all $n\geq 1$ we can remove the absolute value.

$$\frac{n-1}{n^2-2} \leq \frac{n-1}{n} = 1-\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon \iff n<\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}.$$

Thus any $N$ greater than $\max\{1,\frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\}$ has the required property.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can’t see the point of everything starting from “we observe a limit...” (which is dubious, by the way). You already correctly solved the question with algebra of limits.

Comment: Can't you simply use the L'Hospital rule here?

Comment: The line $x_n=0$ as $n\to\infty$ should read $x_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=0$.

Comment: Sorry I should have added they want me to prove using first principles.

Comment: There are several mistakes. Bounding the sequence by $1-\frac 1 n$ does not give you the answer at all.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya What is absolutely correct? There are too many mistakes in what OP has written.

Comment: To see why your (second) proof does not work. Pick for example $\varepsilon=1/10$. Then, $\max\{1,1/(1-\varepsilon)\}=\max\{1,10/9\}=10/9$. Pick $n=N=2>10/9$, but 
$\left\lvert\frac{n-1}{n^2+2}\right\rvert = \frac{1}{6}>\frac{1}{10}=\varepsilon.$

Comment: Thanks Toni I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proof only using the definition.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Pick an $N$ such that $N>1/\varepsilon$. For any $n\geq N$
$$\left\lvert\frac{n-1}{n^2+2}\right\rvert\leq\frac{n}{n^2+2}\leq\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon.$$